# how to fix this error? python <__main__.Employee at 0x7f2358d89910> None

Tags: python

here is the output

```
Enter your ID: 1234

Enter your NAME: Name
 
Enter your AGE: 20 

Enter your Birthdate: 12 

EMPLOYMENT STATUS:  
Enter 1 if you are employed:  
Enter 2 if unemployed:  

1 

Enter 1 if the employment is permanent:

Enter 2 if the employment a job-order: 

2

<__main__.Employee at 0x7f2358d89910>

None
```

the NONE keeps appearing, I want to get the information which is set by the user in display(employee_object) but I don't know hw

---

```py
class Employee(object):

    # initialize values
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = ""
        self.name = ""
        self.age = ""
        self.birthdate = ""
        self.status = ""

    # setter methode for setting values to the class properties
    def set_id(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def set_age(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def set_birthdate(self, birthdate):
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def set_status(self, status):
        self.status = status

    # getter methode for getting values of the class properties
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def get_birthdate(self):
        return self.birthdate

    def get_status(self):
        return self.status


# methode which takes object as an argument and display its properties
def display(employee_object):
    print("ID : ", employee_object.get_id())
    print("Name : ", employee_object.get_name())
    print("Age : ", employee_object.get_age())
    print("Birthdate : ", employee_object.get_birthdate())
    print("Status : ", employee_object.get_status())

    # calls class Employee
    # Main methode of the program


if __name__ == "__main__":
    employee_List = []

    emp_1 = Employee()

    # appending objects to the list
    employee_List.append(emp_1)

    # Initializing each objects of the list
    for employee in employee_List:
        emp_id = input("Enter your ID: ")
        employee.set_id(emp_id)
        emp_name = input("Enter your NAME: ")
        employee.set_name(emp_name)
        emp_age = input("Enter your AGE: ")
        employee.set_age(emp_age)
        emp_birthdate = input("Enter your Birthdate: ")
        employee.set_birthdate(emp_birthdate)
        emp_stat1 = input("EMPLOYMENT STATUS: \nEnter 1 if you are employed: \nEnter 2 if unemployed: \n")
        if emp_stat1 == '1':
            emp_stat2 = input("Enter 1 if the employment is permanent: \nEnter 2 if the employment a job-order: \n")
            if emp_stat2 == '1':
                employee.set_status = "PERMANENT"
            elif emp_stat2 == '2':
                employee.set_status = "JOB ORDER"
        elif emp_stat1 == '2':
            emp_stat2 = input("Enter 1 if you are a freelancer: \nEnter 2 if you are seeking a job: \n ")
            if emp_stat2 == '1':
                employee.set_status = "FREELANCER"
            elif emp_stat2 == '2':
                employee.set_status = "JOB SEEKER"

    # Displaying each objects of the list
    for employee_object in employee_List:
        print(display(employee_object))
```

Comment: Nobody is going to get that error again; likely not even you. You've got a specific class that's personal to your own code, and a memory address. It's not even an error, it's just the standard  `__repr__` of a class

Comment: You should add your code into YOUR initial post, the question, below that the places for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using print, python will call the **str** method of your class, therefore if you want to print readable information you can do it by using

```
print(employee_object)
```

and inserting the **str** method to your class, which could be something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'The employee {self.name} is {self.status}'
```

Answer (score 0):

As no `return` is specified in `display` method, the default is `None` , see [How to prevent Python function from returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498464/how-to-prevent-python-function-from-returning-none)

Your `display` method *shows* things, you don't expected it to return anything, so call it like

```
# Displaying each objects of the list
for employee_object in employee_List:
    display(employee_object)
```

---

Then some python-coding specifics

- [`What's the pythonic way to use getters and setters?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002) using `@property`

  ```
  # If you defined a self._name attribut

  @property
  def name(self):
      return self._name
  @name.setter
  def name(self, name):
      self._name = name

  # GET use : employee.name
  # SET use : employee.name = emp_name
  ```
- Use a constructor with parameters, that nicer

  ```
  class Employee(object):
      def __init__(self, emp_id, name, age, birthdate, status):
          self._id = emp_id
          self._name = name
          self.age = age
          self.birthdate = birthdate
          self.status = status
  ```
- Don't use a outer method `display`, there is a built-in way with `__str__` (or `__repr__`) see [`Difference between __str__ and __repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703), add it to the `Employee` class and it'll be use then you do `print(emp)` where emp is an Employee instance

  ```
  def __str__(self):
      return "\n".join((
          f"ID: {self.id}",
          f"Name: {self.name}",
          f"Age: {self.age}",
          f"Birthdate: {self.birthdate}",
          f"Status: {self.status}",
      ))
  ```

Then the principe you used of *create a list* / *add one instance* / *iterate on the list to populate the instance* isn't a good idea, because you have a fixed amount of employee which isn't dynamically given.

I'd suggest to use a `while` loop that will stops when you enter `stop` at the ID input

```
employee_List = []

while True:
    emp_id = input("Enter your ID: ('stop' to quit)")

    if emp_id == "stop":
        break

    emp_name = input("Enter your NAME: ")
    emp_age = input("Enter your AGE: ")
    emp_birthdate = input("Enter your Birthdate: ")
    emp_stat1 = input("EMPLOYMENT STATUS: \nEnter 1 if you are employed: \nEnter 2 if unemployed: \n")
    if emp_stat1 == '1':
        emp_stat2 = input("Enter 1 if the employment is permanent: \nEnter 2 if the employment a job-order: \n")
        if emp_stat2 == '1':
            emp_status = "PERMANENT"
        elif emp_stat2 == '2':
            emp_status = "JOB ORDER"
    elif emp_stat1 == '2':
        emp_stat2 = input("Enter 1 if you are a freelancer: \nEnter 2 if you are seeking a job: \n ")
        if emp_stat2 == '1':
            emp_status = "FREELANCER"
        elif emp_stat2 == '2':
            emp_status = "JOB SEEKER"

    emp = Employee(emp_id, emp_name, emp_age, emp_birthdate, emp_status)
    employee_List.append(emp)

for employee_object in employee_List:
    print(employee_object, "\n")
```

#### [`FULL CODE`](https://pastebin.com/FreLdtaU)

Comment: <__main__.Employee at 0x7f2358e65d90> I get this when I uses that code

Comment: @FrenchieEstoquiaChua I've just finished my code. You should never have the output you show me, as it is the result of printing an Employee class without have defining `__str__` or `__repr__` and you don't have such